# Freeing Nodes in Linked List

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to free each node in my linked list which was allocated in the addRec function.

CHANGE: Renamed my free funcion to free_list.

My call to free is as follows:

```
main()
{
    struct record * start = NULL;
    runmenu(......,start); //Ends when user chooses option to quit
    .
    . 
    free_list(start);
}

void runmenu(.....,struct record * pstart)
{
    addRec(&start,....);
}

void addRec(struct record ** start,.....)
{
    struct record *toAdd;       
    toAdd = (struct record*)malloc(sizeof(struct record));

    if (*start = NULL)
    {
        *start = toAdd;
    } else {
        struct record *current = start;
        toAdd->next = current->next;
        current->next = toAdd;
        . 
        . //Adds into linked list
    }
}
```

My free function looks like:

```
void free_list(struct record* head)
{
    struct record *temp;

    while((temp = head) != NULL)
    {
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
    }
}
```

I still seem to be having memory leaks. Was this correct?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also not that they say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: This is definitely not correct because you defined `free()` and calling it inside the function will fail into infinite recursion.

Comment: Note: the local variable `start` won't be affected by `runmenu(......,start);` unless the pointer to `start` is passed in `......` or you invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I saw that, and ended up calling free_list in my runmenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've provided your own function called `free()`, which means that the standard one isn't available.  Rename your function `free_list()` and call that in `main()` to release the list.  Inside the (now renamed) `free_list()` function, you still call the standard `free()` function.

Comment: I've changed the name, thanks. So with that simple change this SHOULD work right?

Comment: There's at least a decent chance that you'll fix the leaks with that change, yes. But you should be getting compiler warnings, I think.